# ¿Como puedo saber cuantos pixeles se mueve hacia arriba la barra de scroll cuando se agrega contenido nuevo dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript

¿Como es posible saberlo? Y también quería saber si es posible establecer una cantidad en pixeles para que la barra se desplace cuando llegue nuevo contenido vía javascript ¿Como podría hacer esto último?

Cuando se agrega contenido a un contenedor que tiene scroll esta barra se mueve, o cuando cambia su tamaño.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega lo que lleves

Answer (score 0):

Te refieres a cuántos píxeles se puede desplazar el scroll o te refieres a cuando píxeles hay desde un elemento cuando se hace scroll

Prueba usando:

```
getBoundingClientRect()
```

Te da las distancia de un elemento hacia sus márgenes y teniendo eso y con el evento `scroll` y sus variables que te da la posición exacta de un `scroll` ya puedes calcular y hacer lo que gustes

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. En lo futuro evita responder preguntas de este tipo. La respuesta a la pregunta planteada por el OP: *¿Se puede saber cuantos pixeles se mueve hacia arriba la barra de scroll cuando se agrega contenido nuevo dinamicamente?* es un simple *SI SE PUEDE*. Como puedes apreciar su pregunta no plantea un problema concreto, ni una dificultad. Ni siquiera expone que haya intentado algo. Saludos

Comment: Estaba preguntando un como hacerlo no un si o no...supongo que mi pregunta se dio a entender mal, la he editado..me dices si está mejor, lo agradecería